# What is the android activity for opening sudoku and how do I find how to?

Tags: android, python, appium

I am using appium and using Sudoku app for Android on a Windows 7 machine using Python. If someone can help me find out what the app activity is to opening this and how they were able to figure that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to run adb shell command in command prompt. After that , Open the Suduko app in your device(make sure your device is connected to your laptop/pc) and go back to the command prompt and run the below command :

dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'

The Above command will give you the package name & activity name of the currently focused app.

Answer (score 0):

A simple VM emulate an Android device. Not dificult.

Answer (score 0):

Way to find package and activity is:

1. Connect device (or open emulator)
2. go to console/command line,
3. on device open app.,
4. enter following command

> ```
> dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'
> ```

You should get package name, and activity,

Hope this helps,